# How to use Socket.io Swift in Xcode

Tags: xcode, socket.io

I installed the Socket.io module in the xcode app and when i try to connect to a local server, it gives me an error

**Short error**

> finished with error [-1002] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "nem támogatott URL-cím" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=nem támogatott URL-cím, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=Loading..., NSErrorFailingURLKey=Loading..., _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=( "LocalDownloadTask <3F9281E1-2C34-4EB0-8316-E9F24EC3EFA3>.<5>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <3F9281E1-2C34-4EB0-8316-E9F24EC3EFA3>.<5>, NSUnderlyingError=0x2812feb80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}} 2023-08-01 21:29:21.420330+0200 Chatenium[81149:9363575] [tcp] tcp_input [C4:1] flags=[R.] seq=1715952718, ack=621375818, win=2058 state=CLOSE_WAIT rcv_nxt=1715952718, snd_una=621375818

**Swift**

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://192.168.1.71:3000/message")!, config: [.log(true)])
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
            asd = "cdnd"
        }

        socket.connect()
```

**TS**

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
  namespace: "message",
  maxHttpBufferSize: 1e9,
  transports: ["websocket", "polling"]
})
...
@WebSocketServer()
  server: Server
...
this.server.on('connection', (socket) => {
...
})
```